# Why is the second call not working in locomotive-scroll?

Tags: locomotive-scroll

I have the following code...

```
<div class="jrg-wrapper-main" data-scroll-section>
    <jrg-splash data-scroll
                data-scroll-id="splash"
                data-scroll-call="splash"
    ></jrg-splash>
    <jrg-sidebar data-scroll
                 data-scroll-id="blog"
                 data-scroll-call="sidebar"
                 data-scroll-speed="2"
                 url="./site.config.json"
    ></jrg-sidebar>
</div>
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/locomotive-scroll"></script>
<script type="module">
    console.log("Let us try this");
    const scroll = new window.LocomotiveScroll();
    scroll.on("call", args=>{
        console.log(`Called with ${JSON.stringify(args)}`)
    });
    scroll.on('scroll', (args) => {
        if (typeof args.currentElements['splash'] === 'object') {
            console.log("The call was fired");
        } else {
            console.log("Somewhere else");
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I run this I see...

> Called with "splash"

But even after I scroll down to the sidebar area I don't see the expected...

> Called with "sidebar"

Also I never see the scroll event working.

What am I missing?

[Full Codebase](https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/tree/SCROLL_WORK/modules/esm/jrg-site)

**Update**

I also tried using modular scroll directly like...

```
import modularScroll from "https://unpkg.com/modularscroll@1.0.7/dist/main.esm.js";
const scroll = new modularScroll();
scroll.on("call", args=>{
    console.log(`Called with ${JSON.stringify(args)}`)
});
```

But neither of the calls get printed this way.

**Update 2**

[Here is a simpler version](https://github.com/jrgleason/rollup-demo/blob/SCROLL_WORK/modules/esm/jrg-site/test.html) of what I am trying to do with divs instead of web components...

Answer (score 0):

Use 'call' instead of scroll

```
scroll.on('call', (args) => {
        if (typeof args.currentElements['splash'] === 'object') {
            console.log("The call was fired");
        } else {
            console.log("Somewhere else");
        }
    });
```